# FlutterFlow Stripe integration

Tags: stripe-payments, flutterflow

I am new to flutter flow. I created an app and enabled stripe config on the app. Enabled the test mode in stripe account and added the api keys to flutter stripe settings. It was working initially. My functions are hosted in firebase with api endpoint location us-central. Then something broke so I disabled stripe from flutterflow and deleted the functions in firebase.

I reenabled the stripe integration which created new functions in fire base with Asia-south1 location. Now every time I run the app, the stripe payment always fails because it’s trying to hit us-central1 api endpoint. I cleared the cache folder by running flutter cache clean and ran flutter get pub. But it is still trying the us-central1 endpoint. Please help.

Comment: What error messages are you getting when these requests fail?

Comment: It says Unknown error and in the console, I see Post error to https://us-central-app id-cloud functions.net/initstripetestpayment Cloud call error. I don’t see any triggers to the existing functions in cloud as well

Comment: I'm sure you know this by now but FlutterFlow is pure garbage

Comment: @StackOverflowed Nice try.